# How can I return an int variable after handling it several times in a function?

Tags: function, return, ocaml

I'm writing a function in OCaml that reads a string, validates if it's an integer and converts it to such, then checks if it's included within a range [a,b]. The validations work fine, but I need the function to return the number in the end.

```
let string_is_int s =
  try int_of_string s |> ignore; true
  with Failure _ -> false

let num_between a b = (
  let x = ref 0 in (
  (*validation loop*)
  let op = ref false in
  while not !op do        
    let x_string = read_line () in
    if string_is_int x_string then (
      let x_int = int_of_string x_string in
      if x_int>=a && x_int<=b then (
        op := true; 
        x := x_int;
      )
      else 
        Printf.printf "Invalid, enter again:  ";
    )        
    else 
      Printf.printf "Invalid, enter again:  ";         
  done
  )
)

let n = num_between 1 4;;
```

I've tried adding "x" and "!x" at the end of the while loop, after the parethesis, but I get the error

```
This expression has type unit 
This is not a function; it cannot be applied.
```

I know OCaml doesn't have the key word "return". How do I return the x after the validation loop is complete?

Answer (score 0):

Your basic problem is that the `while` loop in OCaml doesn't return a value. It always returns `()`, known as "unit".

One way to fix this is to write an explicit recursive function of your own that returns the desired value.

Another way is to put the result in a place that can be accessed from outside the loop. In fact, you're already doing this. You just need to add this at the end:

```
done;
!x
```

If you want to try reducing the number of references you're using, you can look at this function that returns the first 3-digit number it finds that is both a square and a palindrome:

```
let look () =
    let is_palindrome k =
        let s = string_of_int k in
        let slen = String.length s in
        let srev = String.init slen (fun i -> s.[slen - i - 1]) in
        s = srev
    in
    let rec loop k =
        if is_palindrome (k * k) then
           k * k
        else
            loop (k + 1)
    in
    loop 10
```

Comment: I just tried adding !x after the loop outside the parentheses of the let x in statement and it works as intended, I just noticed my issue was that I forgot to add the semicolon.
I'll keep in mind the advice about recursive functions, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

This works fine for me:

```
let num_between a b =
  let x = ref 0 in (
  (*validation loop*)
  let op = ref false in
  while not !op do        
    let x_string = read_line () in
    if string_is_int x_string then (
      let x_int = int_of_string x_string in
      if x_int>=a && x_int<=b then (
        op := true; 
        x := x_int;
      )
      else 
        Printf.printf "Invalid, enter again:  ";
    )        
    else 
      Printf.printf "Invalid, enter again:  ";         
  done
  );
  !x
```

It just adds `!x` after the parenthesis after the end of the `while` loop. You may have tried to put it after the wrong closing parenthesis (the one containing the entire function body, which is not needed and which I've removed here; in fact, even the outermost parenthesis I left in here are not needed), or maybe you forgot the semicolon `;` to separate the `!x` from the preceding expression.

Comment: I just tried it that way and now it works as intended, thanks! I'm still having issues knowing when to use semicolons or double semicolons in OCaml, so I didn't know I had to use one after the "let ... in" statement.

Comment: Simple rule: Never use ;;. The ;; is a special token for the interactive interpreter that tells it to evaluate the input you gave it. Otherwise it would wait for more input forever. You never need it / shouldn't use it in real code. Only use it in the interactive top level to say "I'm done typing, show me what that does".

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum to this, there is not need to use any imperative features of OCaml at all to solve this. We just need recursion. The exit case will be successfully reading an int within the specified range.

```
let read_int_between a b =
  match int_of_string_opt @@ read_line () with
  | Some n when n >= a && n <= b -> n
  | _ -> 
      Printf.printf "Invalid, enter again.\n";
      read_int_between a b
```